# Is there a way to split a lined paper scan for model training

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I am experimenting with this HTR repo on github  https://github.com/githubharald/SimpleHTR, but the model can only recognize and train from single word and line scans. I have scans of lined paper and would like to split the image on those lines. I understand I can do this manually with screenshots but programmatically would be better.

Example image:
[image: Handwritten scan]

expected output:
[image: sample output]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.